# Extracting nodes by name

Tags: r, xml2

I am trying to parse an XML file with xml2. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it by specifying the name.

This works:

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

xml <- read_xml(file)
```

-->

```
> xml
{xml_document}
<indexedmzML schemaLocation="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml http://psidev.info/files/ms/mzML/xsd/mzML1.1.2_idx.xsd" xmlns="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
[1] <mzML xmlns="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml  ...
[2] <indexList count="2">\n  <index name="spectrum">\n    <offset idRef="scanId=3027">15181</offset>\n    <offset idRef="scanId=3524">30052</offset> ...
[3] <indexListOffset>73363063</indexListOffset>
[4] <fileChecksum>b8f69d6276d9c4929e74416bc9e3446a173d1894</fileChecksum>
```

And I can extract by position both step-by-step and with xpath:

```
xml_child(xml, 1) %>% xml_child(7) %>% xml_attr("startTimeStamp")
```

_

```
xml_child(xml, "/*[1]/*[7]") %>% xml_attr("startTimeStamp")
```

However my attemps to select by name are failing.

```
> xml_child(xml, "indexedmzML")
{xml_missing}
<NA>
> xml_child(xml, "mzML")
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

and

```
> xml_child(xml, "/indexedmzML")
{xml_missing}
<NA>
> xml_child(xml, "/mzML")
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

and

```
> xml_child(xml, "/mzML/run")
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

Can somehow point me to the solution that is somehow escaping me?

EDIT:

OK here is a data example. With that data what I want is

```
xml_child(xml, 1) %>% xml_child(2) %>% xml_attr("startTimeStamp")
```

But selected by name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<indexedmzML xmlns="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml http://psidev.info/files/ms/mzML/xsd/mzML1.1.2_idx.xsd">
  <mzML xmlns="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml http://psidev.info/files/ms/mzML/xsd/mzML1.1.0.xsd" id="0001_LIP1p_20150803_008_CHCl3-MeOH_1_1" version="1.1.0">

      <dataProcessing id="pwiz_Reader_Agilent_conversion">
        <processingMethod order="0" softwareRef="pwiz">
          <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000544" name="Conversion to mzML" value=""/>
        </processingMethod>
        <processingMethod order="1" softwareRef="pwiz">
          <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000035" name="peak picking" value=""/>
          <userParam name="Agilent/MassHunter peak picking"/>
        </processingMethod>
      </dataProcessing>

    <run id="_x0030_001_LIP1p_20150803_008_CHCl3-MeOH_1_1" defaultInstrumentConfigurationRef="IC1" startTimeStamp="2015-08-03T14:34:14Z" defaultSourceFileRef="MSScan.bin">

    </run>
  </mzML>
</indexedmzML>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to extract all the `startTimeStamp` values from your XML file, you can do:

```
xml %>% xml_find_all("//@startTimeStamp") %>% xml_text()
```

EDIT:

If you want to select it by name, then you need to worry about namespaces.

Indeed,

```
xml %>% xml_child("mzML")
```

will return

```
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

you first need to check the namespaces associated with your XML file:

```
xml_ns(xml)
# d1   <-> http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml
# d2   <-> http://psi.hupo.org/ms/mzml
# xsi  <-> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
# xsi1 <-> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
```

so you'd need to use:

```
xml %>% xml_child("d1:mzML")
```

For the full path to the attribute you're interested in:

```
xml %>% xml_child("d1:mzML") %>% xml_child("d1:run") %>% xml_attr("startTimeStamp")
```

The documentation of the `xml_ns()` gives a little more information, and encourages you to rename your namespaces with more informative names.

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't work for me. I have added a data example now.

Comment: Thanks! That works. But can't I be explicit about the nodes on the path to that attribute? I imagine that would be more efficient. At least in theory.

Comment: Just to check that I tested your line against my original attempt. Yours takes twice as long. Admittedly I had to replicate(10000,...) to get a measurable difference but I'd still like to learn to define the nodes.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to use namespace to access the attribute from its full path

Comment: Superb. That was the missing piece. Thank you very much.